# Using dask module to read large txt file

Tags: python, python-2.7, dask

I am trying to read a large set of data using dask as follows

```
import dask.dataframe as dd

df = dd.read_csv('some_file.txt', sep = '|', header = None)
```

While this works fine and I get a set of partitions, for some reason whenever I tried to set and index as below:

```
df = dd.read_csv('some_file.txt', sep = '|', header = None).set_index('col1')
```

My machine runs out of memory and I can't figure out why

Answer (score 0):

Reseting the index on a large dataset is an expensive operation that generally requires a large out-of-core sort operation.  Dask does this with the [partd](https://github.com/dask/partd) micro-project.

However, partd should still operate in small space, roughly 1GB in RAM.  You would need to provide more information to properly diagnose the issue.

Alternatively, if you can find a way to avoid expensive shuffle / set index operations that's always wise.